# Apache Beam Streaming Write/Read BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam

I'm running a streaming pipeline where I'm trying to write in BigQuery and then reading from it. Is there a way to be sure that what I've just written is there, before reading?
I'm using python:

```
write_result_bigquery = (
            read_pubsub
            | f'Deserialize {TABLE_NAME.capitalize()} JSON' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
            | 'Add Timestamp Field' >>  beam.ParDo(AddTimestamp())
            | 'Log writing' >> beam.ParDo(LogResult())
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                f'{PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET}.{TABLE_NAME}',
                schema = table_schema,
                custom_gcs_temp_location = f'gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/tmpWrite/tmp',
                write_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                create_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                insert_retry_strategy = RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR
                )
        )
_ = write_result_bigquery

#2. READ DATA > LAST PROCESSED TIMESTAMP
read_bigquery_timestamp  = (
            read_pubsub
            | 'Get data' >> beam.Map(read_timestamp_file, GCS_BUCKET, source, timestamp_key_cons_mobile)
            | 'Get timestamp' >> beam.Map(get_timestamp, key = timestamp_key_cons_mobile)
            | 'Create query input' >> beam.Map(generate_query_timestamp, query_ts, PROJECT_ID, DATASET, [TABLE_NAME], [id_col])
            | 'Read BigQuery by timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromBigQueryRetryDoFn(), schema = schema_output)
```

For now I implemented a custom method that throws an exception when the query gives empty results, but it's not efficient and I'm getting other issues. It just forces Dataflow streaming to retry until he finds something.

any ideas?

Comment: Is this done in one pipeline?

Comment: @XQHu it seems to be the next step, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For a streaming pipeline, the default API that Apache Beam uses in it's I/O built-in is the legacy streaming API which withholds access to newly written data for up to 2 minutes.

In order to be able to query data more immediately the new Storage Write API should be used instead as follows:

```py
| "Write to BigQuery"
    >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        f"{PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET}.{TABLE_NAME}",
        schema=table_schema,
        custom_gcs_temp_location=f"gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/tmpWrite/tmp",
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR,
        method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API
    )
```

What the Storage Write API does is buffers the newly written rows and iteratively commits them in batches to the table. This allows you to near immediately access new data from the buffer. This is the recommended way of writing to BigQuery from DataFlow and should work for you.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you! I will try this approach. Do you know more or less what latency in seconds is expected?

Comment: Latency of what? I'm assuming you mean the time between the write and read. In my experience it's not very much, but depending on the size of the data I'd estimate it to be somewhere in the 1-2 second region.